# How to run JavaScript dynamically in a Flex AIR application?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, air

What is the easiest way I can run JavaScript dynamically in a Flex or ActionScript AIR application?

This is what I have so far. It does not work yet and htmlComponent.domWindow is so far null:

```
if (htmlComponent==null) {
    htmlComponent = new HTML();
    htmlComponent.htmlText = "<html><script>"+myJavaScript+"</script><body></body></html>";
    htmlComponent.addEventListener("complete", function(e:Event):void {trace('html load complete');});
    IInvalidating(htmlComponent).validateNow();
}

if (htmlComponent.domWindow && htmlComponent.domWindow.validateXML) {
    result = htmlComponent.domWindow.validateXML(value);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue, is likely that you do not wait for the loading of the content to actually load. So when your code runs, the DOM is still empty.

```
var htmlText:String = "<html><script>"+myJavaScript+"</script><body></body></html>";
htmlLoader = new HTMLLoader();
htmlLoader.loadString(htmlText);

// add a complete handler and don't reference the DOM until it's complete
htmlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadComplete);

function loadComplete(e:Event):void {
    if (htmlLoader.domWindow && htmlLoader.domWindow.myFunction){
       //...do what you need to with the domWindow
    }
}
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could use `StageWebView` or StageWebViewBridge https://code.google.com/p/stagewebviewbridge/

Comment: I don't use Flex (or the HTML component), so do comment on whether this does what you need,

Comment: I did some testing and it looks like HTML component needs to be added to the stage for it to work. Once I did that the "complete" event fired and then I was able to access and run the JavaScript methods. I changed it to use HTMLLoader and it did not need to be added to the stage. I just need to wait for the complete event. Haven't tried the dom initialize event. If you want I can update your answer with the updated code I used.

Comment: Yea, that would likely be helpful to future visitors so please do update it.